# Show contact 7 form in popup

Tags: php, shortcode, css, html

I am creating map link on a image and it has two links to open video and contact form.
I am making popup with *lightbox* but its not working. here is my code..

### HTML

```
<div class="map">
    <img src="http://www.gate7infotech.com/projects/development/MyLuckyBottle/wp-content/themes/twentythirteen/images/home_background.jpg"/>
    <a href="#pop-up-form" id="pop-up-form" shape="rect" coords="31,572,499,1028" class="a lightbox"><?php echo do_shortcode("[contact-form-7 id='4' title='Registration Form']"); ?></a>
    <a href="#" class="b"></a>
    <a href="#" class="c"></a>
</div>
```

### CSS

```
div.map {
    position: relative;
}

div.map > img {
    display: block;
    max-width: 100%;
}

div.map > a {
    display: block;
    position: absolute;
}

div.map > a:hover {
    background-color: rgba(255, 0, 0, .5);
}

div.map > a.a {
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    width: 50%;
    height: 50%;
}

div.map > a.b {
    top: 0;
    left: 50%;
    width: 20%;
    height: 50%;
}

div.map > a.c {
    bottom: 0;
    right: 0;
    width: 20%;
    height: 50%;
}

#pop-up-form { display: none; }
```

Comment: What does *not working* means? The popup doesn't appear? the shortcode doesn't process?  What is not working?

Comment: Means contact form not popping up.

Comment: What script are you using for lightbox?

Comment: I am not using any `script` , I am using **lightbox** plugin

Comment: which lightbox plugin you are using? Do you have a live example of the problem? That would Make it easier to see whats going on.

Comment: There is light box i'm using [Lightbox](https://wordpress.org/plugins/form-lightbox/)

Comment: [Live site i am using on](http://www.gate7infotech.com/projects/development/MyLuckyBottle/)

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/13545/discussion-between-kesar-sisodiya-and-sisir)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So far I guess, you need the following corrections:

```
<div class="map">
    <img src="http://www.gate7infotech.com/projects/development/MyLuckyBottle/wp-content/themes/twentythirteen/images/home_background.jpg"/>
    <a href="#pop-up-form" shape="rect" coords="31,572,499,1028" class="a lightbox">Registration Form</a>
    <a href="#" class="b"></a>
    <a href="#" class="c"></a>
</div>

<?php //This should be a hidden DIV; ?>
<div id="pop-up-form" style="display:none"><?php echo do_shortcode("[contact-form-7 id='4' title='Registration Form']"); ?></div>
```

Comment: It's not useful trick !

Comment: I have made a small change in your answer and i got the result.